# how to get the bpm of an mp3 from its header in android

Tags: android, algorithm, header, mp3, business-process-management

i m trying to calculate the bpm of a song. Normally in iPhone the user use to get the song from iTune where the songs are been listed out along with the pre calculated bpm whereas in android devices how can it be done is there any site to give all those details.

Is there any algorithm to get the bpm of a song from its header. Can any one give me a sample code for that algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mp3 have different tags which contain various info about the MP3 BPM is included in ID3 v2.3 so you have to manually write your parser that will parse the byte of Tag and find out BPM here you will find more info about [MP3 Tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)

Comment: No its raw data written in bytes you have to read it and parse using simple string parsing I am not sure about v2.3 but since I had worked on v1 Tags but read that page its pretty simple and explained over there